# PointSprite in DirectX9

Tags: c++, directx, directx9, particles

I was trying to implement a particle system using PointSprites. Draw calls return D3D_OK but I don't see any particle on the screen. I'm not using Vertex Buffer for the particles, but I use two vectors of vertices and I call the DrawPrimitiveUP function. This is my code:

```
            CreatePntVertices();

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, FALSE);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, FALSE);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);

            pD3DD -> SetFVF(FVF_PNTVERTEX);
            pD3DD -> SetTexture(0, pTex[TEX_POINT]);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSPRITEENABLE, TRUE);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSCALEENABLE, TRUE);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSCALE_A, 0.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSCALE_B, 0.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSCALE_C, 1.0f);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE, 20.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE_MIN, 3.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE_MAX, 50.0f);

            D3DXMatrixIdentity(&mWorld);
            pD3DD -> SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &mWorld);

            pD3DD -> DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_POINTLIST, pntPlanets.size(), (PVOID)pntPlanets.data(), sizeof(PNTVERTEX));

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE, 40.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE_MIN, 9.0f);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSIZE_MAX, 70.0f);

            pD3DD -> DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_POINTLIST, pntStars.size(), (PVOID)pntStars.data(), sizeof(PNTVERTEX));

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, FALSE);

            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, TRUE);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSPRITEENABLE, FALSE);
            pD3DD -> SetRenderState(D3DRS_POINTSCALEENABLE, FALSE);
```

`CreatePntVertices()` is a function that set the position of objects and their color into two vectors of `PNTVERTEX` (`pntStars` and `pntPlanets`). `pTex` is an array of textures. `mWorld` is a `D3DXMATRIX`. `pD3DD` is the Device. `FVF_PNTVERTEX` is set as `(D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)`. I really don't know why it doesn't work, I tried everything to make it work. Maybe, should I use a dynamic vertex buffer instead?

Comment: Have you confirmed your hardware actually supports point-sprites? ``D3DCAPS9.MaxPointSize`` has to be something other than 1.0 or 0.0. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb147281.aspx).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn D3DCAPS9.MaxPointSize returned 8192...

Comment: I compiled another program which used point-sprites, and it worked... so the problem shouldn't be the hardware, but something in the code which I may have forgotten. I'm not able to find out the problem. Could someone tell me which other parameters I have to set? Also I tried to use dynamic VB but the result is the same. I have to add that I draw other things (like spheres or quads) and I don't know if it changes anything if I put this code at the end or at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the source of the problem. After days and days, I understood (at last) that with `SetRenderState` (in DirectX9), `float`s have to be converted into `DWORD`s in this way:

```
*((DWORD*)&f)
```

where `f` is the floating point. I already used this method for fog, but I forgot it and it took me other weeks to learn it again. I hope this answer will help other guys with the same problem!

Comment: I'm amazed you were able to compile your program, passing a `float` to a function that takes a `DWORD`. You didn't even get a warning for that? Additionally, the documentation clearly states that you must binary convert the `float` to a `DWORD` to pass the `float` value to `SetRenderState()`. Always remember to read the docs, and read your compiler output. Aiming for 0 warnings can be a good practice.

Comment: @PandaPajama No, I didn't receive any error! That was the real problem. If I got a message, probably I wouldn't lose so much time searching for the bug. I don't know why, but the program were compiled without warnings. I read the documentation, but I didn't find the statement (although I may have been more careful reading it). I found the problem comparing my program with another program which uses PointSprites. In fact, the difficulty was to find what was going wrong - It's relatively easy to fix a bug if you know what caused it ;)